# Any way so integers are classed as integers with no .0 and floats classed as floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, decimal, division

So. In my program I have a part where I check whether the result of a division sum is an integer or not. For example, `6 / 3 = 2` (True) or `7 / 3 = 1.66` (False). The problem is that when I do a division like `6 / 3`, the result that should be an integer is classed as a float because it comes out as `2.0` instead of `2`. Is there any way so that decimal/float answers are classed as floats with a decimal point, and integer answers are classed as an integer? (The number without the .0 at the end)

I have this now:

```
6 / 3 = 2.0 (float)    
7 / 3 = 1.66 (float)
```

I want this:

```
6 / 3 = 2 (integer)    
7 / 3 = 1.66 (float)
```

Comment: Python 2 or 3? Division behaves differently in them.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`float.is_integer()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=is_integer#float.is_integer).

For example, as expressed by OP:

```
>>> num1 = 6 / 3  # 2.0
>>> num1.is_integer()
True
>>> num2 = 7 / 3  # 2.33
>>> num2.is_integer()
False
```

No need for anything complex here- and implementing this into your function should be easy.

Comment: @DylanJ in which case you should accept the answer in order to let other users know that your problem is solved. Upvotes are also greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question to my `deleted` answer, @AlexThornton. My answer was correct, it just had incorrect syntaxing (which I fixed before it was delted). OP was asking how to detect when the result of a division resulted in an integer with no remainder. I think that you calling for people to flag my answer for deletion was uncalled for.

Comment: @DylanJ you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick below the vote counts. It will turn green once you have accepted.

Answer (score -3):

Does 7 / 3 * 3 = 7?

```
return ((n1 // n2 * n2) == n1)
```

Comment: This only works when `/` is integer division, which it is not in Python 3.

Comment: You're right, @jwodder. In python3 you have to use `//`. You also need to encapsulate the expression in parens for it to actually work. I fixed my answer. I answered with bad syntax from my phone. Maybe I'll avoid doing that going forward.